# AWS Lambda Error + Remote Endpoint not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I was following the Alexa Trivia Skill tutorial on GitHub (*https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia*) and I followed the instructions and during testing I got *Remote Endpoint could not be found...* so then I done further testing in AWS Lambda and I got the following Error:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module './question'",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
"require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
"Object. (/var/task/index.js:16:19)",
"Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
"Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
"Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
"tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
"Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
]
}
```

The Link to the AWS Lambda code is : *https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js*

Any Help will be Greatly Appriciated!

Thanks

***Anush***

Comment: Is the question.js at the same location directory as the index.js ?

Comment: I dont know! Thats what confused me as the tutorial made no mention of uploading the file!

Comment: you have to zip the entire folder and upload it.

Comment: Put all the js files in same directory and make zip of all files. Do not zip parent directory zip all the files and upload it in Lambda function.

Comment: OK so I just upload the js files together and zip it and upload it to lambda?

Comment: Joining it created another error :

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'alexa-sdk'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:15:15)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}